# Is there anyway to bind an event handler to a Tkinter window being moved?

Tags: python, windows-7, window, tkinter, drag

I'm trying to make it so that if a Tkinter window is dragged or moved in any way, a function is called. Is there any way to do this?

This is in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the configure event.

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

search for:

```
<Configure>
The widget changed size (or location, on some platforms). The new size is 
provided in the width and height attributes of the event object passed to the callback.
```